# how can I set a background image in code?

Tags: wpf, textbox, background-image

If I want to set a image as background on a textBox I can use this code in the axml:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="MyImage.jpg" />
 </Grid.Background>
 <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
</Grid>
```

However, I am creating a TextBlock in code, I amtrying this:

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
```

But in this way I don't know how to access to the ImageBrush property.

Which is the way to add a background in code?

Thank so much.

Comment: There is an example in [How to: Add a Watermark to a TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that `MyImage.jpg` is a file in the application's current folder, you could write

```
myTextBox.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyImage.jpg")));
```

If it's a Resource File, you would have to use a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
myTextBox.Background =
    new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyImage.jpg")));
```

Comment: and I can use a Bitmap instead a URI? For example a memorystream or Bitmap.

Comment: BitmapImage can also be created from a Stream. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265190/1136211).