# How do I delete the attachment after email is sent in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-attachments

In my site, User uploads some file from his system and sends email.

```
try
{
  if(Request.Files!=null)
  {
     //save the file to some temp location 
     //Attach the file to email & send
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //log exception
}
finally
{
    //delete the file from temp location
    System.IO.File.Delete(attachmentLocation);
}
```

But if email sendings fails, then I am able to delete the file but in case email is sent successfully,then I get an exception

> The file test.pdf cannot be deleted, as its used by another process

**Is it possible to attach the file without saving it?** 
 
**In case not, then how I do delete the file after sending email?**

FYI:-
This is an AJAX call.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show. Show the email sending and file deletion code.

Comment: finally {  System.IO.File.Delete(attachmentLocation);}

Comment: Please edit code additions into your post - it's often very difficult to read in a comment

Comment: check now..the snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a file being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262548/delete-a-file-being-used-by-another-process)

Comment: You can create an attachment from a stream in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of these two solutions can use the in the first link I think is the solution to your problem

"To Solve this problem, Basically you need to call `Dispose ( )` on the `MailMessage` object ( Of which will then a call `Dispose ( )` on the `Attachment` object , thereby releasing the lock on the file , and Allowing you to delete it) .

There are two obvious ways to do that:

1) Pass the `MailMessage` object to `SendAsync ()` , via the `UserToken` argument . Then , in the `SendCompletedCallback` method , cast to the type `MailMessage e.UserState` , and call `Dispose ( )` on it.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/325303-c%23how-to-delete-attach-file-after-send-mail/

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/360228/how-to-delete-attachment-file-after-it-is-send-as

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it withour saving file

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))    
using (var mailClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25))
using (var message = new MailMessage("me@example.com", "you@example.com", "Just testing", "See attachment..."))
{
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;     

    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "filename.csv", "text/csv"));

    mailClient.Send(message);
}
```

And now you just need to get memorystrem from your file

```
var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
{
   var zz = new MemoryStream(binaryReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength));
}
```