# Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition stops working after starting the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Everytime I start my project even my backup ones, my vs2017 stops working, after stops working ----> restart and then again and again. I don't know why I didn't update my visual studio. I did nothing and I don't know why my vs2017 keeps stop working after starting my project.

The event viewer logs can be found below.

```
Faulting application name: PerfWatson2.exe, version: 15.0.26906.1, time stamp: 0xfc5f0b15
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.608, time stamp: 0x802f667e
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000d9aba
Faulting process id: 0x3618
Faulting application start time: 0x01d34c0166d66c6f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PerfWatson2.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 32a77ca2-f6b3-4a42-892c-6cc77f180aa7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

~~~~~

```
Fault bucket 109168102441, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: PerfWatson2.exe
P2: 15.0.26906.1
P3: fc5f0b15
P4: StackHash_f9a7
P5: 10.0.15063.608
P6: 802f667e
P7: c0000374
P8: PCH_3F_FROM_ntdll+0x000722CC
P9: 
P10:
```

Attached files:
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER90C0.tmp.dmp
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9257.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9266.tmp.csv
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9296.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_PerfWatson2.exe_2c3dcdf7e3b2d714aa01e36af7fcd3d858254_20ada290_25d1adfc

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 32a77ca2-f6b3-4a42-892c-6cc77f180aa7

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
 Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 15.0.27004.2005, time stamp: 0x59e69397
 Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.608, time stamp: 0x802f667e
 Exception code: 0xc0000374
 Fault offset: 0x000d9aba
 Faulting process id: 0x2508
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d34c0165f3308c
 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
 Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
 Report Id: 79fd044e-326b-4eca-b290-71ac25df8cbf
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I hope someone would help me in my problem. Thank you in advance to those people who can help me!

Comment: This question may be a better fit for superuser.com.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662444/how-to-disable-perfwatson2-exe-from-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Might be related with: [How to disable Perfwatson2.exe from Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662444/how-to-disable-perfwatson2-exe-from-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Does this happen with a new solution?  If it does do a repair on visual studio

Comment: Nope. I was using this visual studio 2017 since july but right now I don't know what happen why my projects even the backup ones are not working I think there is a problem in my visual studio. Tried to repair it, didnt work. Tried to reinstall, didnt work also. I'm gonna try these solutions that provided in the previous comment and I'll update you guys if it is working or not thanks guys!