# how to Delete image after uploading image?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi i upload image in my drive with this code

```
public static string SaveImage(this IFormFile imageFile, string fileName, string path)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
        path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path, fileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            imageFile.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

and then upload click remove with this code

```
public static void DeleteImage(this string fileName, string path)
    {
        string imgPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path, fileName);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imgPath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(imgPath);
        }
    }
```

say another proccess used?
i cant deleted

Comment: Check if you have delete permission on the related folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a file being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262548/delete-a-file-being-used-by-another-process)