# How to add an existing item via code in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage, filedialog

I am attempting to copy a selected image to a folder and then want to display it with an Image object. The copying works fine, but when I want to display it it seems like the program cannot find it. Displaying the image only works if I manually use "add existing Item". Is there a way to add it automatically?

Here is my code:

```
string name = "image1";

OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

Nullable<bool> dialogOK = dialog.ShowDialog();

if(dialogOK == true)
{
     File.Copy(dialog.FileName, @"..\..\Images\" + name + ".png", true);


     image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\" + name + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

("image" is defined in xaml)

Comment: is it definitely copying the image into the correct folder (ie: not the project folder but the one in debug/release folders underneath the bin folder)?

Comment: Why not load the file as a byte array for example and create a BitmapImage with it?

Comment: @Slipoch It´s the right folder. I tested it and it works only if I add the existing item manually.

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos Would you be so kind to give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems safer to use an absolute path for loading the BitmapImage:

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var targetFile = @"..\..\Images\" + name + ".png";
    var currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    var targetPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, targetFile);
    var targetDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

    File.Copy(dialog.FileName, targetPath, true);

    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(targetPath));
}
```

In order to release the file directly after loading the BitmapImage, load it from a FileStream:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(targetPath))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}

image.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I already tried a similar thing (giving the absolute path @"C:\Users\..."). The Problem with that is when i want to delete the Image with `File.Delete(@"C:\Users\...")` i get an error because the path is currently used by the picture. Even if i set ´image.Source = null` the garbagecollector won´t delete it. But when i use a relative path this error doesn´t appear but i ran into the issue i described above. So is there a way to do it with a relative path? @Clemens

Comment: A relative path won't help. See the edited answer, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265190/1136211

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the missing piece! Just out of curiosity what is this line for? `Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);`

Comment: It creates all subdirectories of the target path, just in case they do not already exist. So it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks again Clemens!

Comment: This may possibly hit permission issues, especially if it is in program files folders.
You could also create and use a my documents sub folder for storing temporary or program used files.