# How can I save downloaded video file to my project folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, webclient, rest-client

I want to download video file and save it to the project folder.
Here is my current code for the video download and save it to a folder.

```
string savePath = Server.MapPath("DownloadedClip/Record1.mp4");
  //Delete existing file
  if (File.Exists(savePath))
   {
    File.Delete(savePath);
   }
  //Create a new file
  using (File.Create(savePath)) //Exception Occur here
  {
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())                                      
    wc.DownloadFile(url, savePath);
   }
```

When I run the project it throws an exception as "Could not find a part of the path."
How can I solve the issue?

Appreciate your help with this.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm going to guess you haven't created the directory you're trying to save to.

Comment: No, I have a directory as "DownloadedClip" in the project folder.

Comment: That assumes your working directory is the project folder. It may not be.

Comment: I saw one thing that the folder will be deleted after executing if (File.Exists(savePath)) this line and it will not be added by File.Create(savePath) this line.

Comment: How to handle this situation? To check the existing file and add a new one to the same folder.

Comment: I add the line `string fullpath = Path.Combine(savePath, filename);` after savepath and before `if (File.Exists(savePath))` this line. then the issue: "Could not find a part of the path" is resolved. But it throws exception on `wc.DownloadFile(url, savePath);` this line. The exception is "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: Hope this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262548/delete-a-file-being-used-by-another-process/21137207#21137207

Comment: thank you @शेखर issue has been resolved. 
Made changes in code as below:

`string filenameRecording = @"\Record1.mp4";
string fullpathRecording = Server.MapPath("DownloadedClip") + filenameRecording;
//Delete existing file
if (File.Exists(fullpathRecording))
{
File.Delete(fullpathRecording);
}
//Create a new file
using (var fileRecording=File.Create(fullpathRecording))
{
fileRecording.Close();
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
wc.DownloadFile(url, fullpathRecording);
}`